# Timer + Producer-Consumer

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am new to threading and I am trying to learn different concepts.

Right now I am doing a Producer/Consumer pattern with a Timer Thread. The Problem is I have no idea on how to check if all producer and consumer threads finished their processes before letting the Timer thread tick for a certain time and dispose all created producer and consumer thread for the next tick.

Would like to ask for your help and guidance on how to create a work-around for this approach.

Here is my sample code:

```
public class WorkerThread
{
    public BlockingQueue<Item> collection = new BlockingQueue<Item>(100);

    private Timer TimerThread { get; set; }

    public void ThreadTimer()
    {
        this.TimerThread = new Timer(new TimerCallback(StartMonitor), null, 500, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public void StartMonitor(object state)
    {
        List<Thread> producers = new List<Thread>();
        List<Thread> consumers = new List<Thread>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            producers.Add(new Thread(() => RunProducers(this.collection)));
        }

        //TODO: Start all producer threads...

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            consumers.Add(new Thread(() => RunConsumers(this.collection)));
        }

        //TODO: Start all consumer threads...

        //TODO: Let Thread wait until all worker threads are done
        //TODO: Dispose Threads

        TimerThread.Change(5000, Timeout.Infinite);

    }



    public void RunProducers(BlockingQueue<Item> collection)
    {
        List<Item> lsItems = CreateListOfItems();

        foreach(var item in lsItems)
        {
            collection.Add(item);
        }

    }

    public void RunConsumers(BlockingQueue<Item> collection) 
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Item item = collection.Take();
            Console.WriteLine("Processed[{0}] : {1}", item.ID, item.Name);
            //Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    public List<Item> CreateListOfItems()
    {
        List<Item> lsItems = new List<Item>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9999; i++)
        {
            lsItems.Add(new Item() { ID = i, Name = "Item[" + i + "]" });
        }
        return lsItems;
    }

}
```

BlockCollection Implementation (Since our environment is in .Net 3.5 we can't use libraries on the higher verions).

```
public class BlockingQueue<T> 
{
    private readonly Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();
    private readonly int MaxSize;
    public bool closing;

    public BlockingQueue(int maxSize) {
        this.MaxSize = maxSize;
    }

    public void Add(T item) 
    {
        lock(queue)
        {
            while(queue.Count >= this.MaxSize)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(queue);
            }

            queue.Enqueue(item);
            if(queue.Count == 1)
            {
                Monitor.PulseAll(queue);
            }

        }
    }

    public T Take() 
    {
        lock(queue)
        {
            while(queue.Count == 0)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(queue);
            }

            T item = queue.Dequeue();
            if(queue.Count == MaxSize - 1)
            {
                Monitor.PulseAll(queue);
            }
            return item;
        }
    }

    public void Close() 
    {
        lock (queue)
        {
            closing = true;
            Monitor.PulseAll(queue);
        }
    }

    public bool TryDequeue(out T value)
    {
        lock (queue)
        {
            while (queue.Count == 0)
            {
                if (closing)
                {
                    value = default(T);
                    return false;
                }
                Monitor.Wait(queue);
            }
            value = queue.Dequeue();
            if (queue.Count == MaxSize - 1)
            {
                Monitor.PulseAll(queue);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to get rid of the timer, that is not going to end well.  As-is it keeps creating more consumer threads that never end, you have to wait a bit too long to watch it blow up your program.  In the snippet it is only necessary as band-aid for the wonky producer code.  A sensible thing to do is to push an item into the queue whenever it becomes available in whatever real code that produces items.  It that needs to be simulated with a timer then so be it.

Comment: I just updated my code in my local environment a while ago while bench-marking and yes it does create a lot of consumer threads. Right now I tried to only having the Timer Thread create producer thread to queue items every tick

Answer (score 0):

You can just check property IsAlive of all of worker threads. It seems as not very clear code, but it works:

```
public void StartMonitor(object state)
{
        List<Thread> producers = new List<Thread>();
        List<Thread> consumers = new List<Thread>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            producers.Add(new Thread(() => RunProducers(this.collection)));
        }

        //TODO: Start all producer threads...

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            consumers.Add(new Thread(() => RunConsumers(this.collection)));
        }

       //TODO: Let Thread wait until all worker threads are done
        List<Thread> to_check = new List<Thread>(producers);
        to_check.AddRange(consumers);

        while(true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            List<Thread> is_alive = new List<Thread>();
            foreach(Thread t in to_check)
                 if(t.IsAlive)
                     is_alive.Add(t);
            if(is_alive.Count == 0)
                break;
            to_check = is_alive;
        }
        //TODO: Dispose Threads

        TimerThread.Change(5000, Timeout.Infinite);

}
```

Or, maybe somewhat better way:

```
    private int[] _counter = new int[1];
    private int Counter
    {
        get 
        {
            lock (_counter) { return _counter[0]; }
        }
        set 
        {
            lock (_counter) { _counter[0] = value; }
        }

    }

    public void StartMonitor(object state)
    {
        List<Thread> producers = new List<Thread>();
        List<Thread> consumers = new List<Thread>();
        Counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            producers.Add(new Thread(() => { Counter++; RunProducers(this.collection); Counter--; }));
        }

        //TODO: Start all producer threads...

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            consumers.Add(new Thread(() => { Counter++; RunConsumers(this.collection); Counter--; }));
        }

        //TODO: Let Thread wait until all worker threads are done
        List<Thread> to_check = new List<Thread>(producers);
        to_check.AddRange(consumers);

        while (Counter > 0)
            Thread.Sleep(50);

        //TODO: Dispose Threads

        TimerThread.Change(5000, Timeout.Infinite);

    }
```

And to avoid using of Sleep() you can use a Barrier class:

```
    public void StartMonitor(object state)
    {
        List<Thread> producers = new List<Thread>();
        List<Thread> consumers = new List<Thread>();
        int producer_cnt = 1,
            consumer_cnt = 2;

        Barrier b = new Barrier(producer_cnt + consumer_cnt + 1);
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                producers.Add(new Thread(() => { try { RunProducers(this.collection); } finally { b.SignalAndWait(); } }));
            }

            //TODO: Start all producer threads...

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                consumers.Add(new Thread(() => { try { RunConsumers(this.collection); } finally { b.SignalAndWait(); } }));
            }

            //TODO: Let Thread wait until all worker threads are done
            List<Thread> to_check = new List<Thread>(producers);
            to_check.AddRange(consumers);
        }
        finally
        {
            b.SignalAndWait();
        }
        //TODO: Dispose Threads

        TimerThread.Change(5000, Timeout.Infinite);

    }
```